# How to return jsx based on a condition using react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to render jsx based on some condition using react.

what i am trying to do?

I have a common component like so,

```
const ReusableComponent = ({
    hideIcon,
    renderActions,
 }) => {
     return 
         ( 
             {!hideIcon && 
                 <svg/>
             }
             {
                 renderActions ? (
                     <div>{renderActions}</div>
                 ) : output.length > 1 &&
                     selectPlacement === 'top' ? (
                         <Select/>
                     ) : null
              }
          );
      }
```

Now i have two component Component1 and Component2 using this

```
const Component1 = () => {
    const renderActions = (
        <button> Cancel </button>
    );
    return (
        <ReusableComponent
            renderActions,
        />
    );
}

const Component2 = () => {
    const renderActions = (
        <button> Edit </button>
    );
    return (
        <ReusableComponent
            renderActions,
        />
    );
}
```

The above code works fine. but the problem now is as seen from above code, the renderActions is rendered after svg. But for Component2 i want the svg to be rendered after the renderActions.

How can i modify above code, such only for Component2 the svg is rendered after renderActions.

I am new to using react and programming. could someone help me with this. thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have tried something like below

```
const Component2 = () => {
    const renderActions = (
        <button> Edit </button>
    );
    return (
        <ReusableComponent
            renderActions,
            IconToLeft={true}
        />
    );
}

const renderIconToLeft = (
    <>
        {!hideIcon && //icon is rendered first
             <svg/>
         }
        {
            renderActions ? (
                <div>{renderActions}</div>
            ) : output.length > 1 &&
                selectPlacement === 'top' ? (
                     <Select/>
                ) : null
         }
         
         
    </>
);

const renderIconToRight = (
    <>
        {
            renderActions ? (
                <div>{renderActions}</div>
            ) : output.length > 1 &&
                selectPlacement === 'top' ? (
                     <Select/>
                ) : null
         }
         
         {!hideIcon && //icon is rendered last
             <svg/>
         }
     </>  
 
);

const ReusableComponent = ({
    hideIcon,
    renderActions,
    iconToLeft,
 }) => {
     return 
         (
             {iconToLeft ? renderIconToLeft : renderIconToRight} 
         );
      }
```

the above works. but as you see the renderIconToLeft and renderIconToRight methods have the jsx rendered when renderActions is true. In other words how can i make the code more good. not repeating the same code. thanks

Comment: ReusableComponent will always have the SVG before the `div` because that is how it is written. If you want it different you must either: 1) specify a condition where you want the ordering changed, or 2) create a different component. I think the better pattern is to create another component.

Comment: thanks. how can it be done with option1

Comment: @im_baby: i have updated my question with tried solution.

Comment: You can do it with styles. Use flex and in flex-direction, use row-reverse or column-reverse for one of the scenarios.

Comment: @vijayst: thanks could you please add your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
const ReusableComponent = ({
    hideIcon,
    renderActions,
    iconToLeft
 }) => {
     return 
         ( 
             {!hideIcon && iconToLeft &&
                 <svg/>
             }
             {
                 renderActions ? (
                     <div>{renderActions}</div>
                 ) : output.length > 1 &&
                     selectPlacement === 'top' ? (
                         <Select/>
                     ) : null
              }
             {!hideIcon && !iconToLeft &&
                 <svg/>
             }
          );
      }
```